# Bad Message number error in imap_fetchbody function

Tags: php, imap

I have a code to search though emails & if particular string is found, stuff will be done. Below is my code:

```
$date = date( "d-M-Y", strToTime( "-1 days" ));
$email=imap_search($inbox, 'SUBJECT "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender" SINCE
       "'.$date.'"', SE_UID);
if($email){
foreach($email as $email_number) {
    $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1); /* This is Line 18 */
```

This code gives me following error:

```
Warning: imap_fetchbody() [function.imap-fetchbody]: Bad message number in
/home/public_html/example.com/check_invalid_email.php on line 18
```

Now on the above code if I change the subject only like this:

```
$email=imap_search($inbox, 'SUBJECT "Mail delivery failed" SINCE
       "'.$date.'"', SE_UID);
```

It works like a charm with this. For your information there are emails with both the subjects.
I've not included my whole code, please consider everything is alright as changing one line gives me desired results.
Any help with this? I'm not able to find out the cause of it.

Comment: does the `$email` having any value? `print_r` it

Comment: Yes it does have, output is Array([0]=>43)

Comment: you said there are emails with that subject and it is returning only one number `43`, are you sure that you have the email on this 43 index in your mailbox?

Comment: That's because I recently deleted the other emails which I was done with.

Comment: Okay I changed the date because luckily I had two more emails with the same subject in my mailbox, now the output is Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 43 ) with the above warning though. And yes emails do exist.

Comment: have you tried like this `($inbox,$email_number)` removing the 1

Comment: That gives me another warning, Wrong parameter count for imap_fetchbody blah blah

Comment: Are you searching by UID and fetching by sequence number? Do you need to put SE_UID in your fetches or remove it from your search.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Sorry I'm not getting

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to use it like this as you are getting the key,value array

```
foreach($email as $key=>$email_number) {
```

Comment: try to test it by giving the message number manually,lets check it.

Comment: open your mailbox and check the 43rd mail(or any other value in array),and make sure it is same or not

Comment: Mail is opened right in front of me & that's only email in last two days with same Subject, how do I check manually whether it's 43rd email?

Comment: hmmm,just count it from the oldest mail

Comment: I've deleted some emails recently & now the count is no where near 43. It's 16th email.

Comment: then put email no as 16 manually in fetchbody function and test it

Comment: Yeah did that already & it's working fine. What's the solution to it now? This is meant to be automated process & email count is coming wrong, what should I do in this case?